# Node js Upstart script file read

Tags: node.js, upstart, fs

I am working on EC2 instance and I have placed my node application project in the /var/www/. I am using upstart script to start the node application. The upstart script is placed in /etc/init/. In the application I am parsing a file as below to access config vars:

```
var _conf = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config/config.json'));
```

When I run the app in foreground with the command node app.js it works fine. It is able to parse the file into JSON. But when I run the upstart script the following error is thrown.

```
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                                                  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config/config.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/machaao-api/node_modules/machaao-kafka/index.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
[2015-12-09T07:52:05.257Z] (sys) Starting
```

Below is my upstart script:

```
#!upstart
description "API Server"
author      "Author"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 5 20

script
        echo "script started..." >> /var/log/project.log
        echo $$ > /var/run/project-api.pid
        exec node /var/www/project-api/app.js >> /var/log/project-api.log 2>&1
end script

pre-start script
        echo "Pre-start script started..."
        echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/project-api.log
end script

pre-stop script
        echo "Pre-stop script started..."
        rm /var/run/project-api.pid
        echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/project-api.log
end script
```

Can someone explain what is the issue? It says no such file or directory when I know it is there. I am a novice linux user. Is this because of some permission issues?

Comment: You should post the upstart script.

Comment: I have added the upstart script in edit

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need only to `cd` into the node directory and start it from there:

```
exec cd /var/www/project-api && node app.js >> /var/log/project-api.log 2>&1
```

You could also change the app script to get the absolute path so you don't need to cd into the directory:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var _conf = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'config/config.json')));

console.log(_conf);
```

Comment: The code snippet 
`var path = require('path');

var _conf = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'config/config.json')));`
Helped me resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at the moment how node resolves such a relative paths so maybe try something like this, before parsing the json

```
var path = require('path');
console.log(path.resolve('./config/config.json'));
```

and see if it prints an absolute path you wish it to be.